# Why won't my rails form_for with nested models won't remember form values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, form-for, nested-form-for

I have a helper called `user_order` which returns an instance of `Order`. `Order` accepts nested attributes for `User` and `Address`. My (abbreviated) form looks like this:

```
<%= form_for user_order, :url => checkouts_path, :method => :post do |order| %>
  <%= order.fields_for :user_attributes do |user| %>
    <%= user.text_field :email %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Order.rb model code:

```
belongs_to :user
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
validates_associated :user
attr_accessible :user
```

Controller code:

```
def new
  @order = user_order # user_order is a method to get order from session
end

def create
  @order = user_order
  if @order.update_attributes(params[:order])
    redirect_to @order
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Values for user.email are not remembered when the form is submitted with errors and the form is re-rendered.

Why might that be?

Comment: I think you need to post your controller code to figure this out

Comment: Please show the relations between your models.

Comment: I updated the code to include model/controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting, I figured out that this works:

controller:

```
def new
  @order = Order.new
  @order.build_user
end
```

view:

```
<%= form_for @order do |order_fields| %>
  <%= order_fields.order.fields_for :user do |user_fields| %>
    <%= user_fields.text_field :email %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried that controller code from the rails console and made sure it works?

Does your development.log file show it is actually attempting an sql insert statement on form submit?

**Edit:** on reread, it sounds like an insert stmt is happening. nm the second question, although there still may be some info in there.

Comment: I can successfully submit the form, and everything works, so I'm confident the controller code is functioning. It's just when I have errors that it doesn't show the stored values.

Comment: But when you run it with the same parameters as the form, does it drop the email parameter? I've found this is useful to put at the bottom of application.html.erb, fyi: <%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>